# JMeter Appending to existing XML file in single HTTP Request

Tags: xml, http, jmeter

I need to perform load testing while I continuously append to an XML parts from a response. Meaning, I have a load running, HTTP Request which is XML body based, in a loop, and afterwards another HTTP Request which is also XML based.
I need to save part of the responses, and add them to a later on request I'm sending. For example:
I have response built like this:

```
<s:Envelope -Envelope header- 
<s:Body><Response>
  <b:KEY1>Value1</b:KEY1>
  <b:KEY2>Value2</b:KEY2>
  <b:KEY3>Value3</b:KEY3>
  --Continued XML Body-- 
</Response></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Now, my load test is composed from a loop which generates a lot of these responses.
I want to append all the keys and values on each iteration from the loop to a later on request that will be sent (all the keys and values gathered through the loop should be appended to that request
I want to append, after all the transactions of the loop test has finished, the keys and values on each iteration to an existing XML. The test looks like this:

```
-Thread group
--Loop
---Transaction (which I want to extract the keys and values like I mentioned above)
--The request I want to send which contains the values after the loop
```

The thing is that the request after the loop is also an XML file which should be having all those keys and values gathered from the loop iteration.
All the responses from the loop have different **values**, but same **keys** (As the loop runs through 1 request but the request always has different values but same keys).
So the request after the loop should look like this:

```
<s:Envelope -Envelope header- 
<s:Body><Response>
  <b:KEY1>Value1</b:KEY1>
  <b:KEY2>Value2</b:KEY2>
  <b:KEY3>Value3</b:KEY3> 
  <b:KEY1>Value4</b:KEY1>
  <b:KEY2>Value5</b:KEY2>
  <b:KEY3>Value6</b:KEY3>
  <b:KEY1>Value7</b:KEY1>
  <b:KEY2>Value8</b:KEY2>
  <b:KEY3>Value9</b:KEY3>
  <b:KEY1>Value10</b:KEY1>
  <b:KEY2>Value11</b:KEY2>
  <b:KEY3>Value12</b:KEY3>
</Response></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Thanks

Comment: would be helpful to see what have you tried so far, and why it didn't work

Comment: you could extract part of the response with a regular expression, add it to a variable and use that variable in the last request.